# Flutter correct data model

Tags: flutter, types, model

Since im new to flutter im not able to create a correct data model for my api data.

i got this dummy data at the moment:

```
List<Product> productsList = [
  Product(
      id: 1,
      title: "Blue Bag",
      price: 100,
      description: " this is a description",
      category: "Clothes",
      image: "https://fakestoreapi.com/img/81fPKd-2AYL._AC_SL1500_.jpg",
      rating: {rate: 2.1, count: 430}),];
```

i tried to create a model like this:

```
class Product {
  final int? id;
  final String? title;
  final double? price;
  final String? description;
  final String? category;
  final String? image;
  final double? rate;
  final int? count;
  final Map<double, int>? rating;

  Product({
    this.id,
    this.title,
    this.price,
    this.description,
    this.category,
    this.image,
    this.rating,
    this.rate,
    this.count,
  });
}
```

but the rating is wrong  and rating: {rate: 2.1, count: 430} gives me an error.
Im used a little bit in typescript react when i can declare the reating type like
rating: {rate: number, count: number} . How can i do it in flutter?

Comment: change rating: {rate: 2.1, count: 430} to rating: {2.1 : 430} and you don't need rate and count variables if you're just using them for the rating variable

Comment: but I need to access them. and The api sends data like this rating: {rate: 2.1, count: 430} so...

Comment: Map<String, dynamic>? rating = {'rate': 2.1, 'count': 430};